# PHP Class not working for post meta

Tags: php, wordpress, class, oop

This is my first attempt at OOP and coding my own class in practical use.  In a nutshell I am developing a class that will save/update post on each instantiation of the class.  Currently, the below does indeed create a post, but does not work with the post meta.  I have `publish()` method calling a few others when the wp_insert_post is fired.  I dont know if it is the other methods not working, how I am using them or if I did this completely wrong.   How can I get the class to also save the post info like `add_tags()`, `add_categories()` and `add_coauthors()`?

My instantiation:

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);


chdir('../../..');
require_once('wp-load.php' );

  if(isset($_POST['submitted']) && isset($_POST['post_nonce_field']) && wp_verify_nonce($_POST['post_nonce_field'], 'post_nonce')) {

    if($_POST['post']) {
      global $current_user;

      //If we have a post ID lets set it
      if($_POST['post'] != 'new') {
        $post_id = $_POST['post'];
      }

      //Variables from form
      $title = $title = $_POST['postTitle'];
      $content = $_POST['postContent'];
      //$image = $_POST['image'];
      $newAuthors = $_POST['authors'];
      $categories = $_POST['postCategories'];
      $tags = $_POST['postTags'];

      //Assign to class
      $whimkey = new whimkey_posts;
      $whimkey->post_id = $post_id;
      $whimkey->post_status = 'publish';
      $whimkey->author = get_current_user_id();
      $whimkey->title = $title;
      $whimkey->content = $content;
      $whimkey->co_authors = $newAuthors;
      $whimkey->categories = $categories;
      $whimkey->tags = $tags;

      //Process Uploads   
      if (!function_exists('wp_generate_attachment_metadata')){
          require_once(ABSPATH . "wp-admin" . '/includes/image.php');
          require_once(ABSPATH . "wp-admin" . '/includes/file.php');
          require_once(ABSPATH . "wp-admin" . '/includes/media.php');
      }
       if ($_FILES) {
          foreach ($_FILES as $file => $array) {
              if ($_FILES[$file]['error'] !== UPLOAD_ERR_OK) {
                  return "upload error : " . $_FILES[$file]['error'];
              }
              $attach_id = media_handle_upload( $file, $post_id );
          }   
      }

      //Attachment ID if set
      if ($attach_id > 0){
          //and if you want to set that image as Post  then use:
          $whimkey->attach_id = $attach_id;
      }

      //Publish/Save the post
      $whimkey->publish();

      // update $_POST['return']
      $_POST['return'] = add_query_arg( array('post_id' => $post_id), $_POST['return'] ); 
      $link = get_the_permalink($post_id);
      //$link = home_url( '/members/' . $current_user->user_nicename . '/collaborations?updated=true' );
      wp_redirect( $link , 301 );
      exit;

    }
  }
```

And here is my slimmed down version of the class I am writing:

```
if(!class_exists('whimkey_posts')){
    class whimkey_posts {
        public $author;
        public $post_type;
        public $post_status;
        public $taxonomy;

        public $post_id;
        public $title;
        public $content;
        public $co_authors;
        public $attach_id;
        public $tags;
        public $categories;

        public function __construct() {

            $this->author = '';
            $this->post_type = 'whimkey_collabs';
            $this->post_status = '';
            $this->taxonomy = '';

            $this->post_id = '';
            $this->attach_id = '';
            $this->title = '';
            $this->content = '';
            $this->co_authors = array();
            $this->tags = array();
            $this->categories = array();

        }

        public function get_post_id() {
            return $this->post_id;
        }

        public function get_title() {
            return $this->get_title;
        }

        public function get_content() {
            return $this->content;
        }

        public function get_author() {
            return $this->author;
        }

        public function get_attach_id() {
            return $this->attach_id;
        }

        public function get_post_type() {
            return $this->post_type;
        }

        public function get_taxonomy() {
            return $this->taxonomy;
        }

        public function get_co_authors() {
            return $this->co_authors;
        }

        public function get_tags() {
            return $this->tags;
        }

        public function get_categories() {
            return $this->categories;
        }

        public function get_post_status() {
            return $this->post_status;
        }

        public function set_tags() {
            wp_set_post_terms($this->post_id, $this->tags, 'collab_tag');
        }

        public function set_categories() {
            wp_set_post_terms($this->post_id, $this->categories, 'collab_category');
        }

        public function delete() {
            //Delete
            wp_delete_post($this->post_id);
        }

        public function update() {
            //Update
        }

        public function save_meta() {
            //Save Meta
        }

        public function add_image() {
            update_post_meta($this->post_id,'_thumbnail_id',$this->attach_id);
        }

        public function add_coauthors() {
            if(class_exists('coauthors_plus')){

                global $current_user;

              $coAuthor = new coauthors_plus;

              if($this->co_authors) {

                $users_object = array();
                $users_object[] = $current_user->user_login;

                foreach($this->co_authors as $authorID){
                  $user_info = get_userdata($authorID);
                  $username = $user_info->user_nicename;
                  $users_object[] = $username;
                }

                $coAuthor->add_coauthors($this->post_id, $users_object);


              }
            }
            echo '<pre>';
            print_r($this->co_authors);
            echo '</pre>';
        }

        public function publish() {
            //Publish code here
            $post = array(
              'ID'  => $this->post_id,
              'post_status'  => $this->post_status,
              'post_title'  => $this->title,
              'post_content' => $this->content,
              'post_category' => array($this->categories),
              'tags_input'  => array($this->tags),
              'post_type'  => $this->post_type,
              'post_author'  => $this->post_author,
              );  

            // insert the post
            $post_id = wp_insert_post( $post );

            //$this->save_meta();
            if($this->attach_id > 0) {
                $this->add_image();
            }

            $this->set_tags();
            $this->set_categories();
            $this->add_coauthors();
        }

        //public function () {}
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

does it work if you change the row:

```
// insert the post
$post_id = wp_insert_post( $post );
```

to:

```
// insert the post
$this->post_id = wp_insert_post( $post );
```

?

Comment: Lol omg, that was it. . As easy as it was I would have never considered that.  Thanks for the help